# Proving one trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So this problem asks to prove this trigonometric identity,trying two days and I have no idea.If someone could help with this, it'd be very appreciated!
$$\left(\sin \alpha -\sin \beta +1\right)^2=\left(\sin \alpha +\sin \beta \right)^2+\cos ^2\alpha \cdot \cos ^2\beta$$

Comment: What is the source?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot prove it because it is wrong! Take $\alpha=\beta=\pi/2,\;$ then the LHS is 1 but the RHS is 4.